# Android NDK: how to make the command "ndk-gdb --help" work in console?

Tags: android, eclipse, gdb, android-ndk

I would like to execute the following command : "ndk-gdb --help", in the console (I am on Mac OSX).

When I go to my NDK folder in the console and execute this command, I get the following error message: "-bash: ndk-gdb: command not found". I don't understand why I get this message as the ndk-gdb file is clearly present in the folder...

Anyone knows how to solve this issue ?

By the way, I would like to be able to execute this command line ("ndk-gdb --help") or any other command using ndk-gdb from any folder ; how to make this possible ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the NDK folder to your `$PATH` environmental variable.

```
echo 'export PATH=<NDK folder path>:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then close your terminal and open a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I typed: "echo 'export PATH=~/Applications/Android/android-ndk-r7:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile" in Terminal which added "export PATH=~/Applications/Android/android-ndk-r7:$PATH" in bash_profile but still not works. Do you see any syntax mistake or any other issue ? Thanks !!

Comment: Try `.profile` instead of `.bash_profile`, close and open a new terminal and try your command again.

Comment: I did what you recommend. It created a .profile file in my user folder  with  "export PATH=~/Applications/Android/android-ndk-r7:$PATH" inside...but still doesn't work! If you have got any other idea... Thanks again!

Comment: Waitasecond... did you mean to put that ~ in there? What _is_ your path to the NDK? The tilde means "start from my user directory", which might be just fine, but I suspect that you mean `/Applications/Android/...`. If not, no clue. Works for me from .bash_profile.